# Existe alguma maneira de colocar o Input de forma automática?

Tags: c++, input

Há pouco tempo num concurso de programação deparei-me com o problema de ter de colocar mais de 250 Inputs num só problema.
Gostava de saber se existe alguma maneira de colocar os Inputs sem ser 1 por 1, à mão!

Comment: input html? "colocar mais de 250 Inputs num só problema"... que problem?

Comment: Tem algum código?

Comment: Por exemplo: Fazer a média de 200 números. Neste caso ia ter de fazer um grande número de Inputs! Se me enganasse em um só número iria ter de repetir todos os Inputs!

Comment: Neste momento não tenho o código já que o concurso foi realizado numa Universidade e não tive a oportunidade de mantê-lo!

Comment: Pode usar uma linguagem de script como php?

Comment: As linguagens autorizadas no concurso se me lembro eram: C, C++, Java, VB e Pascal!

Comment: respondi antes de você especificar quais linguagens eram permitidas, deseja que eu exclua minha resposta?

Comment: Se não se importar! Pode causar confusão a pessoas com a mesma dúvida que eu!

Comment: Olá @Diorrini11, encontrei um tópico no meta (http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2465/respostas-na-linguagem-errada-devem-ser-exclu%C3%ADdas/2466#2466) que esclarece esta falha de comunicação inicial, estarei deixando a resposta (editarei para esclarescer o engano) para servir como subsidio a futuras respostas

Comment: A pergunta é muito vaga, não há um código inicial, na linguagem que você for fazer isso, talvez o laço `for` possa ajudar.

Comment: Como o colega @qmechanik já mencionou, a pergunta é muito vaga. Por *input* eu também entendi que você quer dizer "entrada de dados", e nesse caso dá pra fazer em qualquer linguagem seguindo o princípio da resposta que você já tem. Mesmo em C++ você pode fazer um laço (um `while`) que repete uma pergunta ao usuário e armazena em uma matriz. Ou seja, isso é realmente trivial. A questão fundamental é: por que isso é importante? (Seria a dificuldade do usuário em digitar manualmente 250 entradas?)

Comment: No caso do exemplo com a média de 200 números, não é mais simples passar para o programa um arquivo texto com os números? Assim, se o usuário "errar" um número, basta editar o arquivo, corrigí-lo, e executar novamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A resposta mais prática é sim. Você pode jogar os inputs que precisa dentro de um arquivo TXT e fazer a leitura no programa.

Se você estiver utilizando Linux da pra usar um redirecionamento de entrada.
Um exemplo bem tosco:

Suponha que vc vai receber os Inputs no seguinte formato

```
N
o
```

Sendo 'N' o número total de inputs e 'o' é a entrada de cada valor, ex.

```
10
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Salvei esse cara como teste.txt

Ex. de leitura em C++

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
        int N = 0;

        std::cin >> N;

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                int o;
                std::cin >> o;
                std::cout << o << std::endl;
        }
}
```

compilando

```
g++ -o teste teste.c
```

Rodando em algum *nix com redirecionamento de input e o resultado

```
adirkuhn: ~ $ ./teste < teste.txt        
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
adirkuhn: ~ $
```

Exemplo 2: **teste2.txt**

```
5
31
32
33
34
35
```

Rodando e resultado:

```
adirkuhn: ~ $ ./teste < teste2.txt 
31
32
33
34
35
adirkuhn: ~ $
```

Answer (score 0):

> Respondi a pergunta antes que o Autor da pergunta especificar todas a linguagens permitidas, porem esta resposta pode ser usada como subsidio (a ideia é literalmente a mesma só muda a linguagem) para a  construção da resposta, para detalhes sobre este conflito de linguagens veja esta discussão: [meta.pt.stackoverflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2465/respostas-na-linguagem-errada-devem-ser-exclu%C3%ADdas/2466#2466)

Se puderes usar uma Linguagem (PHP em meu exemplo) voce pode ir `printando` o que desejar na página.

```
foreach($sites as $site){
    printSite($site);
}

function printSite($site){
    echo '
    <div class="checkbox">
         <label><input type="checkbox" name="site[]" value="'.$site.'">'.$site.'</label>
    </div>
    ';
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

A possibilidade de redirecionar a entrada é uma questão de sobrevivência para o desenvolvimento, teste. Até para a organização
de torneios de computação...

Tomando o caso referido "media de duzentos números" segue alguns exemplos de testes (unix+bash, adapatável a outros ambientes)

0) se tivermos um ficheiro conhecido

```
./myprogram < file
```

1) a média de 200 numeros iguais tem que dar esse número

```
yes 33 | head -200 | ./myprogram
```

tem que dar 33;

2) a média dos números de 1 a 200

```
seq 200 | ./myprogram
```

tem que dar 100.5

3) idem para essa sequência depois de baralhada:

```
seq 200 | shuf | ./myprogram
```

4) eventualmente juntar o teste à makefile:

```
test: myprogram
    diff <(./myprogram < file) <(echo 53)                 && echo OK
    diff <(yes 33 | head -200| ./myprogram) <(echo 33)    && echo OK
    diff <(seq 200 | shuf    | ./myprogram) <(echo 100.5) && echo OK
```